# how to include script inside javascript

Tags: javascript

Please help me, i'd stuck here i dont know how this will be posible.
i want to include a script inside javascript where in i just need to put the script that i include in variable.

here's the code of include.js that i want to include:

```
[{
            "name": "Carrascal",
            "path": "M116,-978,109,-983,111,-986,111,-994,88,-972,28,-912,0,-883,1,-871,5,-864,5,-854,2,-829,3,-824,27,-836,39,-841,52,-846,63,-850,76,-857,95,-866,109,-874,122,-876,130,-877,132,-882,132,-900,132,-907,136,-912,141,-916,150,-917,153,-922,157,-924,155,-932,161,-937,166,-938,168,-934,171,-934,173,-940,177,-944,179,-948,176,-953,170,-955,167,-954,161,-949,157,-946,151,-942,146,-934,138,-926,132,-919,123,-916,114,-926,104,-934,99,-941,95,-947,101,-950,111,-953,115,-957,126,-955,136,-961,136,-966,132,-970,137,-976,136,-984,132,-985,126,-980,127,-972,128,-965,124,-961z"
        }

    ]
```

and here's the code of .js that will call the include.js and set into variable.

```
data = $.getScript('../mapdata/include.js');
```

i'd expect the output will be like this:

```
data = [{
            "name": "Carrascal",
            "path": "M116,-978,109,-983,111,-986,111,-994,88,-972,28,-912,0,-883,1,-871,5,-864,5,-854,2,-829,3,-824,27,-836,39,-841,52,-846,63,-850,76,-857,95,-866,109,-874,122,-876,130,-877,132,-882,132,-900,132,-907,136,-912,141,-916,150,-917,153,-922,157,-924,155,-932,161,-937,166,-938,168,-934,171,-934,173,-940,177,-944,179,-948,176,-953,170,-955,167,-954,161,-949,157,-946,151,-942,146,-934,138,-926,132,-919,123,-916,114,-926,104,-934,99,-941,95,-947,101,-950,111,-953,115,-957,126,-955,136,-961,136,-966,132,-970,137,-976,136,-984,132,-985,126,-980,127,-972,128,-965,124,-961z"
        },

    ];
```

Please help me thankyou ..

Comment: It looks like you actualy want to download json rather than javascript. Try using $.getJSON('../mapdata/include.js'); This will parse the data into a javascript object for you.

Comment: just to retrieve all text inside include.js and set into variable "data"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't necessarily have an include function like other languages.  If you're running your javascript in a browser, then you can include the other script with a script tag, or with ajax.

There are good answers here: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: can i declare like this to my variable?

data='<script src="../mapdata/include.js"></script>'

Answer (score 0):

Not just load javascript, but can be a versatile loader.
Try this:

```html
    <script>
    function include(htmlcontent, toEl, mode){
    toEl = toEl||"head";
    //mode: append = 0, insert = 1, insertAfter =2, insertBefore = 3;
    mode = mode || 0;
    var docElement = (toEl == "html"||toEl == "head"||toEl == "body")? docElement = document.getElementsByTagName(toEl)[0] : docElement = toEl
    var ContHtmlFrag;
    switch (true){
      case htmlcontent == null : 
        alert(new TypeError('The htmlcontent must be filled in'));break;
      case htmlcontent.length == 1 : 
        ContHtmlFrag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlcontent[0]);break;
      case htmlcontent.length >1 : 
        ContHtmlFrag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlcontent);break
    }    
    switch (mode){
      case 0 : docElement.appendChild(ContHtmlFrag);break;
      case 1 : docElement.parentNode.insertBefore(ContHtmlFrag, docElement);break;
      case 2 : docElement.parentNode.insertBefore(ContHtmlFrag, docElement.nextSibling);break;
      case 3 : docElement.parentNode.insertBefore(ContHtmlFrag, docElement.previousSibling);break;
      default:;break;
    }
  };
  /* *********************************** */
  /* Examples of its use                 */
  /* Examples of calling js or css files */
    var cvsCss = "https://aerotwist.com/css/aerotwist.css",
        mnCss  = "http://asciimath.org/css/screen.css",
        cmJs  = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.js",
        cvsJs = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/latest.js?config=AM_CHTML-full",
        mnJs = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.js",
        icon = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico",
        stySht = "stylesheet";

    var tpl_css = function(cont){return `<link href=${cont} rel=${stySht} \/>`} 
    var tpl_ico = function(cont){return `<link href=${cont} rel="shortcut icon" \/>`} 
    var tpl_scr = function(cont){return `<script src=${cont}><\/script>`} 
    include([
      tpl_css(cvsCss),
      tpl_css(mnCss),
      tpl_scr(cmJs),
      tpl_scr(cvsJs),
      tpl_scr(mnJs),
      tpl_ico(icon)
    ],"head");

    /*Example of filling html in element*/
    include([`<div id=\'test\'>
        <div id='A'>  Hello A
           <div id='a'>Hello a</div>
           <div id='b'>Hello b</div>
        </div>
        <div id='B'>Hello B
          <div id='1'>Hello 1</div>
          <div id='2'>Hello 2</div>
        </div>
        <div id='C'>Hello C
          <div id='test1'>Hello 1</div>
          <div id='test2'>Hello 2</div>
        </div>
        <div id='D'>Hello D</div>
    </div>
    `],'body');
    include(['<div>HALLO</div>'],document.getElementById('1'),3);
    include(['<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.js"><\/script>'],document.getElementById('1'),3);

</script>
```

Comment: https://gist.githack.com/dirkncl/0dce481f1818cb018da33150d893c869/raw/25a07873d233c823ce4ea34f409da7c0d50a0158/include.html